# How can I improve my 2D rendering code performance?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, bufferedimage, frame-rate

I'm developing a simple 2D game engine. I finished my renderer but i don't think its performances are ok. I have a `gameScene` class that for now is just a wrapper for an array of `gameElement` objects, that contain an image and information about its position on the screen and its dimensions. I cycle through the array to draw these elements on screen.

I get 68 FPS if I draw a single 800*600 image and it's acceptable but I don't know if it's ok. Performance drops a lot if I have to cycle through the array to draw 100 elements or so. Can I write it in a more efficient way? Or maybe is my FPS count bugged? And should I place the renderer in my game loop or in an overridden `paint` method of a `Canvas` sub-class?

```
public class Game {
    public void loop(double fps) {
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        Scene gameScene = new Scene(1);
    
        String path = "PATH_TO_IMAGE";
        //POPULATE GAMESCENE
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                int width = 800;
                int height = 600;
                gameScene.addElement(new GameElement(path, i*width, j*height));
            }
        }
    
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        gameFrame.add(canvas);
        gameFrame.pack();
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        BufferStrategy bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        BufferedImage canvasImage = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        int[] imagePixels = ((DataBufferInt) canvasImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    
        double frameTime = 1.0 / fps;
        double scale = 1000000000;
        double lastTime = System.nanoTime() / scale;
        int frames = 0;
        double seconds = 0;       
    
        while (true) {
            double newTime = System.nanoTime() / scale;
            if (newTime - lastTime >= frameTime) {
            
                //RENDERING CODE
                for (GameElement elem : gameScene.getElements()) {
                    int[] elemPixels = null;
                    BufferedImage im = elem.getImage();
                    int x = elem.getX();
                    int y = elem.getY();
                    elemPixels = im.getRGB(0, 0, im.getWidth(), im.getHeight(), null, 0, im.getWidth());
                    for (int i = 0; i < im.getHeight(); i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < im.getWidth(); j++) {
                            if (x + j < 800 && y + i < 600) { 
                                imagePixels[800 * (i + y) + j + x] = elemPixels[im.getWidth() * i + j];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                bs.getDrawGraphics().drawImage(canvasImage, 0, 0, null);
                bs.show();
            
                frames += 1;
                seconds += (newTime - lastTime);
                if (seconds >= 1.0) {
                    double FPS = frames / seconds;
                    System.out.println(FPS);
                    seconds = 0;
                    frames = 0;
                }
                lastTime = newTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code **is working** but you are looking for improvements, then your question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pshemo I didn't know about its existence. Should I post a question there?

Comment: IMO it is your choice. I never said your question is off-topic here, but other site is visited by people who specialize in code *improvement* while this one is more general (or maybe even more about code "*repair*"). Problem with other site is that there may not be as many people as here. That is why I believe decision should be yours.

Comment: I'll wait because I already posted here. If I don't get answers I'll ask there. Thank you @Pshemo.

Comment: Please change the awt tag for the swing tag.